# Access individual items in Blazor Virtualized list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a simple collection of "Conversation" like this:

```
public class Conversation
{
    public string? contactName { get; set; }
    public string? thread { get; set; }
    public DateTime newestMsg { get; set; }
}
```

I was originally using @foreach to put these onto a page to display as a scrollable list. I'd load 30 of them from an API call and populate them into "ConversationList":

```
@foreach (var conv in ConversationList)
{
    <div class="conversation">
        <div>@conv.contactName</div>
        <div>@conv.thread</div>
        <div>@conv.newestMsg</div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    Conversation[]? ConversationList = new Conversation[] { };
}
```

I saw Blazor has the Virtualize component which would let me have tons of conversations be scrollable and load on demand, so I changed my code to use it:

```
<Virtualize ItemsProvider="@LoadConversations" Context="conv">
    <ItemContent>
        <div class="conversation">
            <div>@conv.contactName</div>
            <div>@conv.thread</div>
            <div>@conv.newestMsg</div>
        </div>
    </ItemContent>
</Virtualize>

@code {
    private async ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<Conversation>> LoadConversations(ItemsProviderRequest request)
    {
        string apiURL = "https://myAPI:00000?start=" + request.StartIndex + "&limit=" + request.Count;
        ConversationRequest? convRequest = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<ConversationReq>(apiURL);
        if (convRequest != null && convRequest.success)
        {
            return new ItemsProviderResult<Conversation>(convRequest.Conversations, request.StartIndex + request.Count + 4);
        }
        else
        {
            return new ItemsProviderResult<Conversation>(null, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

In my first attempt, I could select a specific item in "ConversationList" and modify it's contents, having the state change on the page. For example, if a new message came in from SignalR, I could select a Conversation by it's "thread" property and update the "newestMsg" datetime.

Now that I have them Virtualized instead, it's not clear how to do this. I can't use Virtualize's "ItemsProvider" and "Items" at the same time. I want to keep the ItemsProvider for the sake of automatic loading while scrolling, knowing the StartIndex and Count automatically.

Comment: Instead of the list listening to signalr have the items listen via a service.  Let them decide if they need a state change. Move your ItemContent into a sub component. I am assuming when the signalr message comes through the data source will be updated. You could also just simply refresh the list if signalr says there has been a change, it will only refresh the current page. The Virtualize component only tracks what is in the last request from the items provider.  https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/Virtualization/Virtualize.cs,b264be4200476a84

Comment: @BrianParker I had no idea the Virtualize automatically applied the bind from what you return in ItemsProvider. That makes so much more sense. 
Do you have an example of how I could make the items listen via a service? Is it more efficient having a bunch of event listeners versus just updating the collection manually during SignalR events?

Comment: If Brian doesn't point you to any resources, you can take a look at one of my repos.  It's a little complicated and may take a little time to "navigate" but there's an implementation of `Virtualize` that ties into a data pipeline provided by DI services.  See the readme for the right startup projects if you download and run it.  The virtualized weather forecast component is here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Database/tree/master/Blazr.Demo.Database.UI/Entities/WeatherForecast/Components.  Ask away for clarification on anything.